# How to dynamic initialize an function local static container variable?

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<Foo> populateContainer() {
  std::vector<Foo> result;
  for(int x : AConstexprIntList) {
     result.push_back(get_foo_using_some_computation(x));
  }
  return result;
}

std::vector<Foo> getConstantFooContainer() {
  const std::vector<Foo>& result = populateContainer();
  return result;
}
```

I am trying to populate a constant vector of `Foo` object. Is above the correct method to use?

Comment: Do you want it to be just constant (meaning that it can't be modified after initialization) or do you want it to be a compile-time constant (meaning `populateContainer` is calculated at compile-time), hinted by the identifier `AConstexprIntList`? There is also no static storage duration variable in your code. What exactly do you mean when you say "static"?

Comment: Please explain what exactly is a "constant vector", because in your post the `vector` is returned by value. The code is at least safe to run but: 1. if your `Foo` has a move ctor then try not using `push_back`, but `emplace_back`; 2. whenever you populate a `vector`, do a `reserve(size_t capacity)` first; 3. if `getConstantFooContainer()` is nothing but returning the result of `populateContainer()`, don't introduce the const-reference `const std::vector<Foo>& result`, making `result` a common `std::vector<Foo>` or simply `return populateContainer();` reduces unnecessary copying.

Comment: @Oasin It doesn't matter whether `push_back` or `emplace_back` is used if `get_foo_using_some_computation` returns a `Foo`. Both will use the move constructor if possible and the copy constructor otherwise.